# Force List<Base> = List<Derived> & Act Like List<Derived>

Tags: c#, list, class, generics, covariance

Classes

```
public class Building
{
    public string Name = "Not To Be Seen";
    ...
}

public class School: Building
{
    public int NoOfRooms = 200;
    public string Address = "123 Main St.";
    ...
}
```

Goal (n some other class / use case)

```
// This is a simple example, in reality this code is far more complex
// the class "School" is private from the program
List<Building> city = new List<School>();
// city will only have properties of the class School (or at least those are the only properties seen)

Console.WriteLine(city[0].NoOfRooms.ToString()) // Outputs 200
Console.WriteLine(city[0].Name) // Should not output anything
```

This seems like it should be very possible depending on correctly converting the lists. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to get this to work. It seems like it involves co-variance, but I do **not** want an immutable list or type. Doesn't C# offer this kind of conversion easily (i.e. base class can fully mimic a derived class)?

Thanks

Comment: Your example is wrong, `List<Person> Jill` doesn't have properties `ClassRoom` it is a list...

Comment: How do you expect a `public` field to not be visible to a derived class?

Comment: And no, you can't have person behave like teacher, accessing properties that belong only to teacher on a person object will never work..... I would probably rethink your inheritance here... and it is my opinion that you don't use inheritance

Comment: You will have to make another class that inherits Person if you don't want Teach to see the name property.  An inherited class always gets all the properties of the base class.

Comment: `Jill` is of type `List<Person>`, not `Person`, so it neither has a `ClassRoom` nor a `Name`. Second: Since `Teacher` _inherits_ from `Person` it _does_ have a `Name`. So it's a little unclear what you are asking for. Third: a `List<Teacher>` is _not_ a `List<Person>`, so it's not assignable. Even in the `IList<T>` interface `T` is invariant as it's an input as well as an ouput value.

Comment: @CallumLinington oops. I fixed that now.

Comment: I think the thought "a _base_ class can fully mimic a _derived_ class" shows a total misunderstanding of OOP. It's rather the other way round, if at all.

Comment: `School` *extends* `Building` by deriving from it. Therefore it is a superset of what is offered by `Building`, not a subset. That's just how inheritance works.

Comment: @RenéVogt Not at all. I am just trying to get a very specific implementation of objects and lists.

Comment: @B1313 - well, you say you understand OO, and you just want a specific implementation... except that the specific implementation you want runs counter to the principles of OO, so I think RenéVogt is making a very reasonable observation.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Well, if we want to be technical, his observation should actually be that I may not be grasping the concept of Inheritance in OOP, but not that I don't understand OOP in the broad scope. The reasoning behind my implementation is that I am trying to hide the derived class from the eyes of the rest of the program and have the Base class act like the objects of the derived class in a list is a natural result of have a list of the base class. To be clearer, I am trying to have the base class spoof the derived class (when needed) without the program knowing anything special is done

Comment: @B1313 - Using the new example: you can store a `School` in a `List<Building>`; you can't assign a `List<School>` to a variable of type `List<Building>`. If the rest of the program doesn't know about `School`, then it can't have a list to which only `School`s can be added. To have the variable "act like" its real type though the rest of the program sees it through a base type reference is polymorphism (see `virtual` in C#). And no, if you don't understand inheritance *or polymorphism*, then you don't understand OOP; so quit complaining and start learning form what we're telling you.

Answer (score 0):

**Update** - Since you completely changed your example, I'll update my answer to reflect the new example.  I'm doing this only once; so to anyone reading, if my answer seems out of sync with the question, it's because OP is making unnecessary changes during edits.

---

There are a few problems here.  It is not possible for a `List<Base>` variable to refer to a `List<Derived>` instance.  This is because, for example, `List<Base>` must implement operations for adding a `Base` instance to the `List`, and a `List<Derived>` cannot support such an operation.

More generally, the reference type (type as which the variable is declared) defines the interface by which calling code can use the value.  So if you need to be able to say `city[0].NoOfRooms` in your example, then `city` must be declared as a `List<School>`.  A `School` could still be stored in a `List<Building>`, but when you get an item from such a list you would have to try casting to `School` before using the `NoOfRooms` property.  (And it should be noted that if you find yourself doing this, it suggests a design error.)

The other part of your question has to do with hiding the `Name` property.

In some languages you could get such an effect through "private inheritance" - but that's not a thing in C#.  The closest thing you could do is to have `School` *not* by derived from `Building`, but possibly contain a (private) `Building`-typed field or property.  Then, of course, it wouldn't be possible to store a `School` in a `List<Building>` at all.

The other approach would be to have `School` override the `Name` property with a getter that returns nothing, which actually is closer to what your code comments suggest.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments to your question, an object in your `List<Building>` can not be arbitrarily cast into a `School` unless it was originally constructed as a `School` object (or a class derived from `School`). Consider what would happen if you had another class called `Hospital` derived from `Building` and that had its own property say `NumberOfPatients` and this was one of the objects in that list. You just can't cast a `Hospital` instance into a `School` and call the properties available only on `School` - it just wouldn't make sense to do this.

That said you can still have a `List<Building>` store any kind of `Building` objects, including the derived ones (such that you have a mixed list containing `Building`, `School` and `Hospital` objects). Then you could get an enumeration of objects of a specific derived type via Linq `OfType` (add to the top of your file `using System.Linq;`). So something like `buildingList.OfType<School>()` would give you an enumeration of only `School` objects, which you can now to iterate through and call methods/properties only available on `School`.